# After few time form open and close in xamarin android application slow

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was trying to check the performance of my Xamarin application. While I was reviewing the application, sometimes I felt the application was slow when the form opened and closed.

Here is the output of the logs.

```
[View] requestLayout() improperly called by 
crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewContainer{6bd65b5 V.E...... ......ID 
0,0-1080,2115} during layout: running second layout pass
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=20.76ms min=4.90ms max=407.70ms 
count=49
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=17.37ms min=5.31ms max=281.48ms 
count=49
[View] requestLayout() improperly called by 
crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewContainer{ee6ddca V.E...... ......ID 
0,0-1080,2115} during layout: running second layout pass
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=27.24ms min=5.63ms max=655.06ms 
count=49
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=15.11ms min=5.71ms max=223.53ms 
 count=48
[ame.pcrwsmobil] NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 15993(626KB) 
 AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 5447KB/10MB, paused 
1.190ms,106us total 110.076ms
[View] requestLayout() improperly called by
crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.ScrollViewContainer{9c288ef V.E...... ......ID 
0,0-1080,2115} during layout: running second layout pass
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=25.51ms min=5.87ms max=602.22ms 
count=49
[EGL_emulation] app_time_stats: avg=18.73ms min=6.01ms max=193.78ms 
count=42
```

Nothing's running anything in form load.
[image: Here is the functions and design]
Device log
[image: Device log]

[image]

Comment: To investigate performance, test a **Release** build, on an **actual device** (with no debugger attached). Or if you must use an emulator, still do not attach debugger - "Debug / Start without debugging" (or after download, launch from emulator's home screen instead of from VS). Then use Tools / Android / Device Log to see the log info while run.

Comment: The log alone is not enought info to diagnose the problem. Provide the view(s) and the code realted to it (loading and actions).

Comment: Thanks for the replay. both enumerator and the actual device can see the same performance.

Comment: Is there a way to share images or links in StackOverflow?

Comment: You can  upload images  using the `image` menu in your thread.

Comment: @ Leo M  I have attached more details for you.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have attached the log.

Answer (score 1):

You keep pushing new pages onto the navigation stack. You need to use pushmodal to open a modal page and then

```
await Navigation.PopModalAsync()
```

to remove it from the stack. Otherwise you just keep opening new pages and they consume memory.

Comment: Thanks for the support. It works. :) :) . I am really new to Xamarin development and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi  @ErangaDayarathne,   please mark the reply as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems.  Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This was the correct answered. Thanks for the support.